# How can i write to a File after a Certain Key is Pressed and then get to a new Line

Tags: python, file

I am very new to python but i dont know what i can do to fix my problem.
This underneath is my code but but the file does not collect all the things it should to write there. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.
Edit:

Thank you its fixed now but i have another problem that the things arent appearing very fast and its kinda laggy. Is there anything that would help?(I already tried to set down the time.sleep part.

```
import time

from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

from pynput.keyboard import *
import mouse




def press_on(key):

    print('Press ON: {}'.format(key))

    if key == key.right:
        mouse.move(1028, 350, absolute=True, duration=0.02)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        mouse.click("left")
        time.sleep(0.3)
        with open('Get Position.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write('RIGHT')
            f.write('\n')
            f.close()


    if key == key.down:
        mouse.move(959, 350, absolute=True, duration=0.02)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        mouse.click("left")
        time.sleep(0.3)

        with open('Get Position.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write('MID')
            f.write('\n')
            f.close()



def press_off(key):
    print('Press OFF: {}'.format(key))
    if key == Key.up:
        return False

with Listener(on_press = press_on, on_release = press_off) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in append mode - 'a' and not 'w'.

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
  f.write('line\n')

with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
  f.write('this line will be appended\n')
```

Comment: Thank you that works, but there is only one problem the code is quite laggy so it needs a few seconds to register is there anything that would help? And btw i changed the time.sleep time to 0.0001